# Python selenium try, except

Tags: python, python-2.7

If i am running something like below:

```
title = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='title']").text
views = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='count']").text
likes = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='votesUp']").text
```

but for some reason on said page one of these elements cannot be found, how do I tell python to just pass and move on. It seems to crash on me from time to time. I have tried the usual but as i have not verified entirely what title is it will not work.

I am creating a simple screen scraper that just trawls through a website opening videos and grabbing information. I am then exporting this information into csv like below:

```
b = open('test.csv', 'ab')
a = unicodecsv.writer(b)
data = [[title, views, likes]]
a.writerows(data)
```

As some of these pages may not contain the xpath it is crashing, is there a way around this?

Comment: Does it give you an error message? If so, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you talk about Selenium you mean WebDriver, if so, it comes with `common.exceptions` module that contains all exceptions that you can catch in your `try: except:` block, for example

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`

More exceptions here https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html